# Truth error while trying to find all equal minimum values in array, then retrieve indices

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, minimum

I'm trying to find all the minimum values in an array and retrieve their indices.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[1,4]])
minE = np.min(a)
ax,ay = np.unravel_index(minE, a.shape)
```

only returns `minE = 1`, `ax, ay = 0 1`

Can anyone help me out in a way that would also provide indices for all equal value minima (here, indices for both 1's)?

Comment: Please show us a snippet of code, not only the `min()` function.

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio sorry, I've cleaned it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you looking for this:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,4,2]])
np.where(x == np.amin(x))
```

Comment: awesome!! Thank you so much :)